# Как настроить внешний вид placeholder'а?

Tags: вёрстка

Имеется шаблон блога, в котором есть форма регистрации. Поля формы почти прозрачные, поэтому за ними просвечивается фон, при этом плейсхолдеры в полях белого цвета и жирные. Как можно сделать плейсхолдеры белыми и жирными, если поле почти прозрачное?

Comment: Через js делаете в полях текст белым и жирным, а при клике, убираете текст плейсхолдера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В дополнение к [ответу @Dmitry Shishkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537526/200881). Теперь Placeholder убирается при фокусе.**

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
input {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0392b;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Firefox 19+ */

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c0392b;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Firefox 18- */

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c0392b;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Сверху код Дмитрия. Ниже - мой. */

:focus {
  outline: none;
}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Плейсхолдер">
```

Собственно, сама часть, ответственная за то, чтобы placeholder прятался.

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы)

Comment: @Кирилл отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ Дмитрия решением тоже. Его ответ лег в основу, а мой является лишь дополнением, доведшим задачу до конца.

Comment: А зачем плейсхолдер убирать при фокусе? Или это просто дизайнерская задумка?

Comment: @DmitryShishkin Так ведь в комментариях под вашим ответом автор попросил

Comment: @DmitryShishkin А нет, извините. Это даже не автор просил, а я тут же поспешил ответ накалякать

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
input {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#fff; font-weight: bold;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#c0392b; font-weight: bold;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#c0392b; font-weight: bold;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#c0392b; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Плейсхолдер">
```

Comment: А чего он не убирается, когда мышка внутри?

Comment: Нужно начать печатать. Это особенность плейсхолдеров.

Comment: Так неинтересно

Comment: @DmitryShishkin добавил эту фичу в своем ответе.